# How to convert array to this pointing array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I am trying to use the package [Normalize](https://metacpan.org/pod/Normalize), but I have the data in arrays (`@x`), not in some pointing arrays which the package requires for normalization.

Wanted data format in a pointing array as hash

```
my %xx = ('1' => 22.595451, '2' => 20.089094, '3' => 17.380813);
```

Current data format

```
my @x = qw/22.595451 20.089094 17.380813/;
```

i.e. `('22.595451', '20.089094', '17.380813')`.

How can you convert the data to the pointing data-structure?

Comment: Some resources that might be helpful: [the basic datatypes, three](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861) on PerlMonks; [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, with IEEE-754 doubles "... give 15–17 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the same number of significant digits, then the final string should match the original. If an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17 significant digits and then converted back to double, then the final number must match the original." OTOH, if any operations involve differing magnitudes, the last digits start losing meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your array by reference instead of using a hash. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Normalize;

my @x = qw/ 22.595451 20.089094 17.380813 /;

my $norm = Normalize->new(round_to => 1e-16);

$norm->normalize_to_max(\@x);

print "$_\n" for @x;
```

which will normalize the contents of `@x` in place

Comment: @Masi: You need to create the `$norm` object as described in the documentation you link to `my $norm = Normalize->new`

Comment: @Masi: You are unlikely to get better than 12 significant figures, but you can set the rounding when you create the object with `Normalize->new(round_to => 1e-16)`

Comment: I have some problem with this normalization - it is not optimal. It normalizes the first value to 1.0000... How can you do the normalization better? My own normalization sets 1st value `0.982698386894082` instead giving much more optimal result. I think I need to add some offset and multiplication. Any default way for this about how to proceed?

Comment: @Masi: Or you can disable rounding by using `$norm->set(round_obj => Math::Round::Var::Fake->new);`

Comment: @Masi: The `Normalize` module is designed to normalize the maximum value to 1 and won't do anything else. What do you mean by *optimal*? You should start a new question and explain your requirement in detail

Comment: @Masi: `$x[0] / 0.982698386894082 ` is equal to `22.9932716908341`. Are you saying that you want the values normalised relative to the integer closest to the maximum value?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This equivalence has been deduced through a long manipulation for my practical case. So the first value should be normalized to the `0.982...`, not to `1.000...`. Everything else should then go somewhere. They can be slightly over >1.0.

Comment: @Masi: So what should happen in the *general* case of, say `2.8`, `2.4`, `3.1`, `1.1`? Do you want everything normalised relative to the *first* value `2.8`, the *maximum* value `3.1`, the *nearest integer to the first value* `3`, or something else?

Comment: Everything (only these values `22.595451 20.089094 17.380813`) should be normalized such that the first value gets value `0.982...` which has been deduced empirically. It does not matter if some values are more than `1.000...` because the physical event is nearly optimally described that way. It would be nice to know how customizable approach this `Normalize` or any other package is, since currently, I have to write each time my own `Normalize` function in special situations.

Comment: @Masi: I'm sorry but you're not defining the problem properly. ***Everything (only these values ...*** means nothing. I've tried very hard to help you, but if you won't spend some time to explain your problem then I can't do any more

Comment: Yes, I know. Your answer is completely enough and excellent for this thread! I cannot explain the situation here more without taking into account more details of the challenge. This is not suitable anymore for this thread. The real data set is much bigger and consists of two lines where I am doing also averaging, transformations and finally normalization. This thread is only a simplification about the normalization where I am studying how well this package is suitable for my challenge. - Any package which does not stick to 1.0000 as max can be useful in normalization.

Comment: @Masi: Once the normalisation base has been calculated, the job that `Normalize` does can be written in a single Perl statement `$_ /= $factor for @x` The module just uses `my $factor = max(@x)` buit you can equally use `my $factor = $x[0] / 0.982698386894082` to get the specific result that you're asking for. I can understand that there are other calculations behind the scenes, but there is no reason why you can't explain your problem in terms of an arbitrary function so that `my $factor = f(@x)`. But for some reason you write in vague generalisations that don't explain anything

Comment: The function is this one `$y[$i] = 2 * ($y[$i] - $slope * $x[$i] - $offset) / $normal;` where `my $slope = ($slope_pos + $slope_neg) / 2; my $offset = ($const_neg + $const_pos) / 2; my $normal = abs($const_pos - $const_neg);` based on lineFit's least square fitting on those two lines.

Comment: @Masi: That's fine. It looks like a best-fit of some sort. But you're missing my point, that it doesn't matter what the function is if you define precisely how you want to normalise your data. `Normalize` is probably not the tool for the job, but if you can calculate `$factor` then `$_ /= $factor for @x` is all that you need

Comment: You are right! So no need to use the `Normalize` package at all - at least, I cannot include `Normalize` directly to any part of my challenge, but has to keep in my customized function. So just divide by the factor `$normal` finally as I have done in my initial attempt - is your point.

Comment: @Masi: I can't tell for sure, but I think so. That's all that `Normalize` does after all, but with the addition of supporting hashes as well as arrays and rounding to a specific accuracy -- neither of which you want. As for ***but has to keep in my customized function*** I doubt if it's useful even there, but I haven't seen your code

Answer (score 2):

The actual name for what you call a "pointing array" is a *hash*, which is a type of *associative array*.

```
my %xx; $xx{$_} = $x[$_] for 0..$#x;
```

-or-

```
my %xx = map { $_ => $x[$_] } 0..$#x;
```

---

That said, Borodin pointed out that that module's functions accept a reference to an array as well as a reference to a hash. That means you don't need to do

```
my %xx = map { $_ => $x[$_] } 0..$#x;
$norm->normalize_to_max(\%xx);
```

since you can simply do

```
$norm->normalize_to_max(\@x);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert an array into a hash.

```
my %hash;
@hash{ keys @array } = values @array;
```